# Matlab - dynamical adding data in structure

Tags: matlab, dynamic, data-structures

Matlab’s Image Processing Toolbox contains the function bwconncomp which gives a Matlab structure containing (among others) the number of objects and a list of the pixels in each component.

I would like to produce a similar output for the intersections of a skeleton [found by bwmorph(matrix,'branchpoints')]. However, I am unfamiliar with how to declare an open structure.

My intent is to search through the matrix and adding information regarding each as I go along. Since the some of the point given by 'branchpoints' can represent the same intersection I do not know the number of intersections, or the number of pixels needed to store in my pixel id list.

How can I keep adding pixels into the cell containing all pixels for a given intersection (CC.PixelIdcList in the output from bwconncomp)

Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you gave a numerical example of the structure you are trying to build...

Comment: I have relized that I could use bwconncomp on the matrix from bwmorph(matrix,'branchpoints').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bwconncomp on the matrix from bwmorph(matrix,'branchpoints').

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain exactly what you're asking but here are two ways of adding fields to a struct:

Firstly we can just add fields by putting values in them. These fields can be arrays or cell arrays and you can grow them dynamically just like any matlab array:

```
s.p{1} = 5;
s.p{2} = 10;
s.p{3} = 'I''m a string!';
```

Secondly, if you really have to, you can dynamically create field names using strings:

```
for n = 1:3
  name = ['p', num2str(n)];
  s.(name) = n/10;
end
```

This results in:

```
disp(s)

scalar structure containing the fields:

p = 
{
  [1,1] =  5
  [1,2] =  10
  [1,3] = I'm a string!
}
p1 =  0.10000
p2 =  0.20000
p3 =  0.30000
```